# TypeError in Python script in file "<template>"

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and inherited a script that refers to other scripts and modules. When I run it from the Windows command prompt, I encounter the following message:

> File `"<template>"`, line 37, in top-level template code
>   TypeError: float argument required, not str

I'd like to troubleshoot this, but I don't know which .py file is being referred to by `"<template>"`.

The code of the main file is below:

```
from markdown import markdown
import flowerpoint
from re import sub
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
from os.path import abspath
from os import getcwd
from time import sleep
import jinja2
from jinjaFunctions import jinjaFunctions

class FlowerParser:

    template = None
    outputFile = None
    mdHtml = None
    jinjaHtml = None

    class FlowerHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
        from flowertags import FlowerTags

        curTextbox = None
        slideInitialized = False

        justAddedParagraph = True
        curFont = flowerpoint.PPTextFormat()
        tags = None

        excelMode = False
        excelWorkbooks = {}

        def _getWorkbook(self, workbookName):
            wkbk = self.excelWorkbooks.get(workbookName, None)
            if wkbk:
                return wkbk
            else:
                raise Exception("Workbook not found: %s" % workbookName)

        def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
            self.tags.handleTag(tag, attrs, True)

        def handle_endtag(self, tag):
            self.tags.handleTag(tag, None, False)

        def handle_data(self, data):
            #self.addText(sub(" +"," ",sub("\n"," ",data)))
            self.addText(sub(" +"," ",sub("\n|\r","",sub("\n(?!$)"," ",data))))

        def addText(self, text, format=True, isSpace=False):
            if len(text) == 0:
                return
            self.justAddedParagraph = isSpace
            if self.slideInitialized and self.curTextbox is not None:
                if format:
                    flowerpoint.addText(self.curTextbox, text, self.curFont)
                else:
                    flowerpoint.addText(self.curTextbox, text, None)

        def __init__(self):
            HTMLParser.__init__(self)
            self.tags = self.FlowerTags(self)

        def __init__(self, inputFile, template, outputFile):
            self.template = template
            self.outputFile = outputFile
                with open(inputFile,"r") as mdInputFile:
                    jinjaEnv = jinja2.Environment()
                    jinjaEnv.globals.update(zip=zip, int=int, float=float)
                    jinjaTemplate = jinjaEnv.from_string(mdInputFile.read())
                    jinjaTemplate = jinjaTemplate.render(**jinjaFunctions)

                    self.jinjaHtml = jinjaTemplate
                    print self.jinjaHtml
                    self.mdHtml = sub("&gt;",">",sub("&lt;","<", markdown(jinjaTemplate)))

                    print self.mdHtml

        def run(self):
            flowerpoint.loadFromTemplate(self.template, self.outputFile)
            parser = self.FlowerHTMLParser()
            parser.flowerpoint = flowerpoint
            parser.feed(self.mdHtml)
            flowerpoint.close()
```

Comment: If possible provide the code please, it makes yours and ours lives pleasant. :)

Comment: Sorry, here is the code.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide the complete code not only the main class. Put the complete code in a zip archive and upload it somewhere, from where we can download it. Mention the download link in your post.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the program was calling a markdown file. Line 37 of that markdown file is:

```
{{'%.f' %  getCell(excelFile, 'Count', 16, 13)}} Temporary staffing<br>
```

This expected a float argument but the cell referenced (position 16, 13) was blank and thus not a float. This produced the error.